# Angular how to shuffle array er

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, shuffle

I have simple array look like this

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
```

Also attach my array structure in image

I need to shuffle this mean i want some time second array come one first. etc

Something like this `[{"id":"2"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"3"}]` or on every shuffle different result come
Any one can tell how is it possible ?

[image]

I have try this but dont know how to console the new shuffled array ?

```
start(CategoryID){
console.log(CategoryID);
    this.api.getQuestions(CategoryID).subscribe((data: any)=>{
      console.log(data);
      data = this.shuffle(data);

    });

}

 shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: I already try with tehese questions. But its not working in my situtaion because n these question therye is only 1 array. and i have multiple array in one.

Comment: @UmaiZ can you put your console after this line  data = this.shuffle(data);

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let array=[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}] 
array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but its not working. Nothing is shuffling or changing

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: maybe its for 3 array ? I am doing same as you say but nothing is chaning

Comment: @sacgro why 0.5 ?

Comment: @PardeepJain To make the possibility of getting true/false 50%

Answer (score 0):

Hope it Helps!!

```
shufflingArray (value: any[]) {

    let items: any[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      items.push(value[i]);
    }

    // reversing items array
    for (let i = items.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [items[i], items[j]] = [items[j], items[i]];
    }
    return items;
}
```